# Array in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to deploy array in jQuery and java script? 
i need to explore in this topic? Can any one help me?

Comment: Please tell us what you mean with *deploying an array*. Do you mean defining/initializing it? In any way, this might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: jQuery **is** JavaScript. There is no difference. It is just `var a = ['some', 'array'];`.

Comment: Of course it's possible in jQuery: [jQuery is really great and does all things.](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As jQuery is JavaScript, creating an array is simply:

```
var arr = ["an", "array"]; // array with 2 values
var arr = []; // empty array
```

There is never a reason to use the `Array` constructor.

**[Read more about arrays.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)**

---

Because someone mentioned *associative arrays*:

Although they might look like arrays, they are not arrays (in a strict JavaScript sense). This kind of data structure is normally created using **objects** (here with object literal notation. Same thing: There is no reason to use the `Object` constructor.):

```
var obj = {
    foo: "bar"
};
```

In JavaScript you can access object properties with either dot notation (`obj.foo`) or array notation (`obj['foo']`). This is convenient but you should not make the mistake to confuse objects and arrays.

Especially you should not mix it and attach properties to an array (like an other answer shows) if you don't know how/why it works (in short: Nearly everything in JavaScript is an object, also arrays. That does not mean that you should use them as such.).

**[Read more about objects.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects)**

Comment: Is there any option like array list in java script?

Comment: @selladurai: You mean ArrayList like in Java? No, but arrays in JavaScript are already dynamic. I think most (if not all) methods that are provided by ArrayList or also provided for arrays in JS.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript:

```
var arr = new Array();
```

Read more about the [JS Array object here](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_obj_array.asp).

Comment: (a) `var arr = [];` is even better(and shorter) and (b) don't reference w3schools.com. Read http://w3fools.com/ for *why*.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple array:

```
var my_array = new Array();
my_array[0] = "Hello";
my_array[1] = "World";
```

Which could also be set like this:

```
var my_array = ["Hello", "World"];
```

An associative array:

```
var my_array = new Array();

my_array["karl"] = new Array();
my_array["karl"]["age"] = 18;

my_array["viktor"] = new Array();
my_array["viktor"]["age"] = 18;
```

To work with arrays in jQuery you have for example the method `each()` that can be used like this:

```
$(my_array).each(function(item){
// here you can interact with the item
});
```

Comment: Use plain **objects** (`{}`) for "associative arrays". This kind of "abuses" arrays and is difficult to understand for beginners (e.g. `my_array.length` will still give you `0`).

Comment: Your associative array is incorrect. You are not setting string keys on the Array but adding new properties to the Array object. Any object could be substituted here with the same result. You will not be able to use any of the Array methods by using the array object.

Comment: @meouw - "setting string keys on the Array" and "adding new properties to the Array object" are exactly the same thing. Arrays are objects with a special length property and access to Array.prototype's methods, that's all. It's "keys" are just numeric string properties.

Comment: @RobG: Yes and no. As @meouw said, you cannot use the array functions on these elements (and as I said, `arr.length` will not work). But using an array like this suggests you can. So using a plain object is better.